# get the very high quality screenshot using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'am trying to get the very high quality screenshots using this phantomjs script.But the screenshot which i'am getting is not that great.It's not that clear.The clarity sucks in the screenshot.How do i get the very high quality screenshot??can anyone help me in this!!....

this is how my code looks like....

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1200 };
page.zoomfactor = 1;
page.open('myurl', function(status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Load the address!');
            page.dpi = 300;
            page.render('d:/screenshots/Newpdf.png',{format: 'png', quality: '100'});
            phantom.exit();
        }, 300000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 
    }

  //phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have to be more specific about about "The clarity sucks". I'm assuming the Background-image appears to be blurry. In that case: The Background-image is [this one](https://videmo.aujas.com/savp/assets/aujasloginbg-3398a67e8fd82c90422016bfe8292ea9.jpg):

- It's a *.jpg, wich is a [Lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) and already has visible Artifacts. Phantom can't magically increase the quality of JPEGs.
- It's only 1920x1200 - and thus will be blurry if your screenshot is bigger than that. Phantom can't magically increase the quality of upscaled images - although it doesn't seem like you're trying to do this

The same problems might apply to [the logo](https://videmo.aujas.com/savp/assets/savp_logo_2-7e7072299c12fecce2695d81ed0f27ae.png) - this might have blurry and/or badly anti-aliased edges because of massive downscaling (1890x827 original, but shown as ~153.73x84 - where the fraction-of-a-pixel-width might be another problem).

Solution: use images in the exact size they're shown on your site and pre-optimize the images in Photoshop/Gimp/Whatever. Avoid scaling. Avoid lossy compression. Try to avoid %-sizes wich might cause the images to use fractions of pixels.